# How to create a content tagging system for two models in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Edited my question to make it more clear. And I am sorry if what i'm asking is obvious or easy to solve, I am just starting out.

Hello, I am developing a website which has 2 models for the content: Article and Comic. Now I want a system that allows me to tag Articles and Comics with certain keywords. These keywords can then be used to retrieve a list of objects from both the models and display them.

At first, I set up the system as follows:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    .....
class Comic(models.Model):
    .....
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    comic = models.ForeignKey(Comic)
```

However, this did not work out.

Then I tried implementing 2 different tag models for the 2 different models: ArticleTag and ComicTag, in the following way:

```
class Article(models.Model):
   .....
class ArticleTag(models.Model):
   tag = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
   article = models.ForeignKey(Article)

class Comic(models.Model):
    .....
class ComicTag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    comic = models.ForeignKey(Comic)
```

This also did not work, as I was able to get a list of tags of an article, but **I could not get a list of articles that had the same tag**. And also it was using 2 different tag models so that was also not preferable.

A user suggested a ManyToManyField based on the previous information I had provided. However, how would this exactly work?

Now, what is the best way to create a content tagging system using Django? It should preferably work with just 3 models: Article, Comic and Tag, not 4 like I tried. In conclusion, I want a system that lets me get a list of objects from 2 models using one single tag. So, I would really appreciate help of any kind as I am an amateur programming (pretty obvious) and I am completely stumped by this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Basically something like the following. It's more intuitive if you change the name of `ArticleTag.tag` to `ArticleTag.name`. I've also added a `related_name` field to the M2M relationship so you can retrieve an article based on its tags using `Article.objects.filter(tags__name="tag_name_here")`. In the reverse direction, you could get all the tags for an article using `ArticleTag.objects.filter(article__title="article_name_here")`.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    .....
class ArticleTag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article, related_name="tags")
```

**[EDIT based on your updated question]**

Based on your update, you could do this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
   .....

class Comic(models.Model):
    .....

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    articles = models.ManyToManyField(
        Article, 
        related_name="tags", 
        blank=True, 
        null=True
    )
    comics = models.ManyToManyField(
        Comic, 
        related_name="tags", 
        blank=True, 
        null=True
    )
```

This way an `Article`/`Comic` can have many different tags, and any one tag can tag many different articles/comics. The `blank=True`, `null=True` means that you don't *have* to have an associated comic/article with a given tag, i.e., one tag could happen tag only comics but no articles.

To get a list of articles with the same tag:

```
Article.objects.filter(tags__name="your_tag_name")
```

Comment: Wait, won't Article.objects.filter(tags__name = 'tag_name_here') get me a list of articles with that tag?

Comment: @TahmidKhanNafee you're correct - updated my answer, thanks!

Comment: Oh now it makes sense, anyway, I updated the question with more information as the previous one was pretty lackluster. However, thanks for this answer.

Comment: @TahmidKhanNafee updated - just FYI generally you should post a new question if your edit makes it that much different - you'll get more traffic for it. Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh damn, I thought it was against the rule or something. Oh and thank you again for the updated answer, I will try it out.

Comment: It works! Although I did add the manytomanyfield relationship to both Article and Comic model separately instead of Tag. It made it much easier to manage the content from admin. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ideally that is how it needs to be, as in it makes more sense to think articles/Comics containing tags.